# div's event always called when click checkbox in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm binding two events on elements like following:

```
<div class="view">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit">
</div>

$(function(){
    $(".view").bind('dblclick', show1);
    $(".edit").bind('click',show2);
});

function show1(){
    console.info('here');
}

function show2(){
    console.info('hi');
}
```

It is normal in Firefox, but in Chrome, div's event always called when click checkbox.

FYI: http://jsfiddle.net/dMcnJ/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(".view").bind('dblclick', show1);
    $(".edit").bind('click',show2);
    // Disable event bubbling on dblclick
    $(".edit").bind('dblclick',function(e) { e.stopPropagation();});
});

function show1(){
    console.info('here');
}

function show2(event){  
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.info('hi');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dMcnJ/9/

Answer (score 1):

It's called event bubbling. Do the following:

```
function show2(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.info('hi');
}
```

Comment: This is not the case since events are different: `dblclick` and `click`. I have the same behavior in Firefox which is expected